# visualforce page login page with list has no rows

Tags: visualforce

[image]

```
public with sharing class gmController {
public gmail__c g{get; set;}

    public gmController() {

    }

public gmail__c opp{get; set;}
    public gmController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
opp = (gmail__c)controller.getRecord();
g=new gmail__c ();
    }

public gmail__c reg{get; set;}
public list<gmail__c> gmailuser{get; set;}
public Boolean Match{get; set;}
public Boolean NotMatch{get; set;}

PageReference pageRef;
public PageReference signin(){

gmailuser=new list<gmail__c>();
string s=opp.USERNAME__c;
string p=opp.password__c;
string x=[select USERNAME__c from gmail__c where USERNAME__c =: opp.USERNAME__c].USERNAME__c;
string y=[select password__c from gmail__c where password__c =: opp.password__c].password__c;

if(x!=null & y!=null){

 if(s==x & p==y ){



 pageRef=new PageReference('/apex/welcom');
 pageRef.setRedirect(true);
return pageRef;
 }
 else{
 }


 }       
return pageRef;
}

public PageReference forgotpassword(){
PageReference forppage= null;
        forppage= Page.customizeloginpage;
        return Page.forppage;

}


public PageReference save(){
insert g;
PageReference p=new PageReference('/apex/forpage');
p.setRedirect(true);
return p;
}public boolean displayPopup {get; set;}     

    public void closePopup() {        
        displayPopup = false;    
    }     
    public void showPopup() {     
        displayPopup = true; 

    }
    public string getpword(){

    string y=[select password__c from gmail__c where USERNAME__c =:opp.USERNAME__c].password__c;
system.debug(y);

return opp.password__c=y;



    }

}
<apex:page standardController="gmail__c" extensions="gmController">
<apex:form >
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var myWindow = window.open("https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/windowpopup", "MsgWindow", "width=600,top=100,left=350, height=490");

}
</script>
<apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel value="User Name" for="resource" />
<apex:inputField value="{!gmail__c.USERNAME__c}" id="resource"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:outputlabel value="Password" for="password"/>
<apex:inputSecret value="{!gmail__c.password__c}"  id="password"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


</apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:pageblockButtons location="bottom">
<apex:commandButton value="login" action="{!signin}" reRender="notmatch"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Register" onclick="myFunction();" rerender="tstpopup"/>
<apex:commandLink value="forgotpassword" action="{!forgotpassword}" />
</apex:pageblockButtons>

</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:outputPanel id="tstpopup">
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}"/>
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
                This isthe popup windowr.<br/><br/><br/>

                <apex:outputLabel value="name"><apex:inputField value="{!g.Name}"/></apex:outputLabel><br/>
                <apex:outputLabel value="username"><apex:inputField value="{!g.USERNAME__c}"/></apex:outputLabel><br/>
                <apex:outputLabel value="password"><apex:inputSecret value="{!g.password__c}"/></apex:outputLabel><br/>
                <apex:commandButton value="save from here" action="{!save}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Hide Pop up" action="{!closePopup}" rerender="tstpopup"/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <style type="text/css">
        .custPopup{
            background-color: white;
            border-width: 4px;
            border-style: solid;
            z-index: 9999;
            left: 50%;
            padding:10px;
            position: absolute;
            /* These are the 3 css properties you will need to change so the popup 
            displays in the center of the screen. First set the width. Then set 
            margin-left to negative half of what the width is. You can add 
            the height property for a fixed size pop up if you want.*/
            width: 500px;
            margin-left: -250px;
            top:100px;
        }
        .popupBackground{
            background-color:black;
            opacity: 0.20;
            filter: alpha(opacity = 20);
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 9998;
        }
        </style>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

the problem is with login action.if i give the credentials that are not exixts in the database,then give giving the error.if i give the credentials that are exists in database,,works fine.

Comment: Are you seriously storing password as plaintext ?

Comment: Iam fresher,I would really appreciate some help in solving this

Comment: yes  mr.karthikselva

Comment: http://plaintextoffenders.com/about/

Comment: sir,my issuse is not with the plaintext or something else,if login with the details that are not available in the database,then it gives error at line 24(variable x,if username is not available)and for password also,(if password is not available in database then it is throwing exception at line 25 variable y)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting exceptions is that the queries may not find the record

```
string x=[select USERNAME__c from gmail__c where USERNAME__c =: opp.USERNAME__c].USERNAME__c;
```

One way around this is as follows

```
Gmail__c[] gmXList = [select username__c from gmail__c where username__c = :opp.username__c];
if (gmXList.size() == 1) {.. normal processing flow}
else 
if (gmXList.size() > 1) {...error? .. choose most recent? ... }
else { ..error - no User found}
```

Comment: it is not working sir list<User[]> cannot be asigned to list<gmail__c>

Comment: my bad; edited answer. You really need better variable names (x and y are not very transparent). I tend to make my variable names reflective of the underlying sobject, go something like `gm...` for variables about  custom object `Gmail__c`. If you stick to a convention, your coding goes faster and is less error prone